# Python 3.7.2 Windows x86 executable installer does not allow single user installation

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to install latest Python (3.7.3) on a couple of Windows 10 PCs without admin privileges. For this purpose I downloaded the corresponding executable installer from [download link](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/python-3.7.3.exe).

When executing the installer, some of the Windows PCs show the *Install launcher for all users (recommended)* option force checked. I can't proceed with the installation since I'm asked for admin privileges even though Python is to be installed on a user directory with reading and writing permissions.

Why is the *Install launcher for all users (recommended)* option force checked? Could it have something to do with existing launcher installations? Is there any way around?

[image: Install launcher for all users (recommended)]

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why, but once I uninstalled existing Python Launcher I was able to uncheck the *Install launcher for all users* option and install Python without admin privileges.

Comment: For anyone reading, this is because it involves the launcher. See: https://bugs.python.org/issue41847